# Finding N formula (Backward Difference)

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to find the N formula of $▽^n f(x)=x^2+x$ Where $h=1$
So far, I reached to this point,

$▽ f(x)=f(x)-f(x-h)$

$ =x^2+x-[(x-h)^2+(x-h)]$

$= x^2+x-[x^2-2xh+h^2+x-h]$

$= x^2+x-x^2+2xh-h^2-x+h$

$= 2xh-h^2+h$

What to do next?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question since it's not clear. What is the "$N$ formula"?

Comment: @EthanBolker N formula in Backward difference

Comment: Do you mean the Nth difference?

Comment: @martycohen Yes .

Answer (score 1):

The binomial theorem
appears in 
one of its many guises here.

$▽ ^{(n)} f(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}f(x-kh)
$.

This can
(and should, as an exercise)
be proved by induction.

Then get
$f(x-kh)$
and substitute.